# jQuery sort, find uniques & wrap inside element

Tags: jquery

I'm having List Elements similar to this :

```
<ul id="alpha-list">
    <li>Angel</li>
    <li>Ball</li>
    <li>Cat</li>
    <li>Bat</li>
    <li>Dog</li>
    <li>Apple</li>
</ul>
```

I've managed to sort this list items alphabetically using (return a - b) function.

but I want to wrap each list element within parent "ul li" so that final result should look similar to this :

```
<ul id="alpha-list">
    <li data-alphabet="A">
        <ul>
           <li>Angel</li>
           <li>Apple</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li data-alphabet="B">
        <ul>
           <li>Ball</li>
           <li>Bat</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    ..... 
</ul>
```

How to find unique alphabets among this & then wrap them inside new elements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function () {
    //First create a list of objects containing the unique set of characters and the correspondign li elements
    var map = {}, list = [];
    $('#alpha-list li').each(function () {
        var char = $.trim($(this).text())[0];
        var array = map[char];
        if (!array) {
            array = [];
            map[char] = array;
            list.push({
                char: char,
                array: array
            })
        }
        array.push(this);
    });

    //sort the list alphabetically
    list.sort(function (obj1, obj2) {
        return obj1.char.localeCompare(obj2.char)
    });

    //then create the new structure
    $.each(list, function (_, item) {
        var $li = $('<li />', {
            'data-alphabet': item.char
        }).appendTo('#alpha-list');
        var $ul = $('<ul />').append(item.array).appendTo($li);
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/B29qh/)

Answer (score 0):

This is want you want.

```
$('#alpha-list').find('li').sort(function (a, b) {
    a = $(a).text();
    b = $(b).text();
    if (a < b) {
        return -1
    } else if (a > b) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}).each(function (idx, e) {
    var val = $(e).text();
    var wrap = $('#alpha-list').find('[data-alphabet="' + val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + '"]');
    if (wrap.length == 0) {
        console.log('create');
        $('#alpha-list').append('<ul data-alphabet="' + val.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + '">' + e.outerHTML + '</ul>');
    } else {
        console.log('append');
        wrap.append($(e))
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I did it. example here: http://jsbin.com/IwOZiPas/1

```
var items = [];
ordered_list = "";
$('#alpha-list li').each(function(){
   items.push($(this).html());
});
items.sort();
current_letter="";
for(var i = 0, l = items.length; i < l; i++)
{

  if(items[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() != current_letter){
    ordered_list +="</ul><li data-alphabet='"+items[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase()+"'>"+items[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() +"</li><ul></li><li>"+items[i]+"</li>";  
    current_letter = items[i].substr(0,1).toUpperCase() ;
  }

  else
  ordered_list +="<li>"+items[i]+"</li>";  
}

$('#alpha-list').html(ordered_list);
```